# HTML shows � symbol when rendered on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsom, online

I created a .HTML file in SharePoint Document library using JSOM. when I view the HTML file in google chrome it shows � symbol at start of each tag. below are the codes that I used to create HTML file

```
var uploadedDocument;
function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName,UploadclientContext,oList)  
{  
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
        var i, length, out = '';  
        for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1)  
        {  
            out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
        }  
        var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
        createInfo.set_url(fileName);  
        createInfo.set_overwrite(true);

        createInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());  
        fileContent =out; 
        for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++)   
        {  
            createInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));  
        } 
         uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)  

        UploadclientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
        UploadclientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess(fileName), QueryFailure);  
}
```

this is HTML is get in browser[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below line in your html file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-8">
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I would like to add another thing here that this HTML is rendering perfectly fine in IE ,Edge and Firefox so I don't think it has anything to do with the encoding of the HTML

Comment: The meta tag might not be the solution but this **is** an encoding issue

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman if it is an encoding issue then I think it should show the same error on every browser rather it is rendering perfectly fine on IE,Edge and Firefox.I think it has something to do with the method I used to ready the arraybuffer

Comment: semantics .. you **encoded** something incorrect..